# PERL + match exactly string(from left side) in line

Tags: perl

I have problem with the following perl command
How to match all "1234" strings in file, but if some characters jointed before "1234" then it will not match, my problem is: if the string "1234" in the middle of the line then it not match why?

The perl command:

```
perl  -pe 's/OLD/NEW/ if /^1234/' file
```

Example of what need to match:

```
a ass 1234= OLD
bbb ddd 1234= OLD
 1234= OLD
```

Example of what not need to match:

```
a1234=  OLD
sss q1234=  OLD
```

Comment: Stop posting duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `^` matches "the beginning of the line". Try removing that character in the regular expression. Replace it with a space character.

Answer (score 2):

Change the `^` to `\b`. That will match only if the `1234` is the start of a word. (If necessary, see `perldoc perlre` for more information on what constitutes a 'word'!)

Comment: I have problem when the parameter is *.55555
then its not matched??

Comment: You have edited the question substantially from the previous one, and now everyone's answers don't make sense... I think it would be better to revert your question to how it was before, then ask a new question with the new problem... if you post the link here, I'm sure everyone who's looked at this question will take a look at that one :-)

Comment: I reverted it back to the previous question since yael has reposted the newer question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110329/perl-how-to-match-special-characters/3110368#3110368